# Remove items 30 minutes after their duration

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

In a table in my database, I have a date and time column (datetime) that stores the time when the event will occur. How can I delete
that event 30 minutes after it happened?

Comment: Scheduled task? Windows service? SQL Agent task?

Comment: But do you even need to delete it. Its easier just to filter them out in your query.

Comment: @Dale K Yes.That would be scheduled. I researched and found something about creating a trigger or an event, but I really didn't understand how to do it

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule a task to run.  This would do:

```
delete from t
    where datetimecol < dateadd(minute, -30, getdate());
```

But how do you prevent people from seeing this until it is deleted?  Use a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*
    from t
    where datetimecol >= dateadd(minute, -30, getdate());
```

Anyone accessing the view will only see the more recent events.  Periodically -- once a day, once a week, you can schedule a job to clean out the older events.